# Libgdx get texture from Texture Atlas with findRegion

Tags: libgdx

I have this code

```
textureAtlas = TextureAtlas("atlas.atlas")

val box = textureAtlas.findRegion("box")
```

I want to create a texture with "box". Is it possible? box.texture return the original texture, not the regioned. Oh and I don't want to use Sprite and SpriteBatch. I need this in 3D, not 2D.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using it in 3D, there's no reason to use a TextureAtlas. You can't extract a Texture from a TextureRegion, so you'd either need to work directly with the Pixmap and create a new Pixmap from a region of the source image file, or do some fancy UV manipulation to your mesh to get it to use that particular region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextureAtlas actually not separating pieces. When you get region from atlas its just saying that this is the area you gonna use (u,v,u2,v2) and this is original reference to whole texture.

This is why batch.draw(Texture) and batch.draw(TextureRegion) are not same in use.

However taking part of picture as texture is possible.

- You can use pixmap to do it.

  First generate pixmap from atlas texture. Then create new empty pixmap in size of "box" area you want. Then assign pixel arrays and generate texture from your new pixmap.

It may be quite expensive due to your Textureatlas size.

- You can use framebuffer. 
  Create FBbuilder and build new frame buffer.Draw texture region to this buffer and get texture from it.

Problem here is the sizes of texture will be same as viewport/screen sizes.I guess you can create new camera to change it to sizes you want.

```
GLFrameBuffer.FrameBufferBuilder frameBufferBuilder = new GLFrameBuffer.FrameBufferBuilder(widthofBox, heightofBox);
    frameBufferBuilder.addColorTextureAttachment(GL30.GL_RGBA8, GL30.GL_RGBA, GL30.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
    frameBuffer = frameBufferBuilder.build();
    OrthographicCamera c = new OrthographicCamera(widthofBox, heightofBox);
    c.up.set(0, 1, 0);
    c.direction.set(0, 0, -1);
    c.position.set(widthofBox / 2, heightofBox / 2, 0f);
    c.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(c.combined);
    frameBuffer.begin();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(boxregion...)
    batch.end();
    frameBuffer.end();
    Texture texturefbo = frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture();
```

Texturefbo will be y flipped. You can fix this with texture draw method by setting scaleY to -1 or You can scale scaleY to -1 while drawing on framebuffer or can change camera like this

```
up.set(0, -1, 0);
direction.set(0, 0, 1);
```

to flip to camera on y axis.

Last thing came to my mind is mipmapping this texture.Its also not so hard.

```
    texturefbo.bind();
    Gdx.gl.glGenerateMipmap(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    texturefbo.setFilter(Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear, 
    Texture.TextureFilter.MipMapLinearLinear);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do this:

```
Texture boxTexture = new TextureRegion(textureAtlas.findRegion("box")).getTexture();
```

Comment: it is the whole texture, not the regioned one, I think I have to create a custom shader for that